# calculate the day of my Birtday

Tags: php, web-deployment

how i calculate that on what day my Birthday Comes Using **php** like on Monday, Tuesday and so on..

Comment: Use the date() in php and use the l (lowercase 'L') feature (A full textual representation of the day of the week).  Here is a link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: No the idea is not clear, could you explain it a bit more?
And could you pleas provide what you have tried? SO is to help solving problems, not providingin tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this code might need some tweaking but it should work.
And here is a link of how I figured it out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
//create a date of John
$birth_date =  mktime(0,0,0,1,6,1991);
//determine if John's birthday has passed this year
if (date("m",$birth_date) > date("m") 
   && (date("d",$birth_date) > date("d"))){
       $year = date("Y");  
}else {
       $year = date("Y")+1;
} 
//find his next birthday
$next_birth_date = mktime(0,0,0,
     date("m",$birth_date),
     date("d",$birth_date),
     $year);
//echo the day of his next birthday
echo date('l', $next_birth_date);
```

Comment: can you please explain the steps.. where the date of user written?

Comment: its not work as i understand My Birthday is on 30-January-1991 by your formula its shows Wednesday where My Birthday on was Friday?

Comment: I see where my error is, give me a min to fix it for you.

Comment: NP make sure that my newest code works.  I forgot to take into consideration that John may have already had his birthday this year

Comment: why you can use that next_birth_date = mktime(0,0,0,
     date("m",$birth_date),
     date("d",$birth_date),
     date("Y"));  Explain its working process

Comment: because if you have a birthday in January and it currently is March.  That will determine your Johns next birthday of 1.6.2015 when it should be 1.6.2016

Comment: date('m')for month so why that mkt() and at which stage you compare current day with my Birthday?

Comment: @SariRahal Why advance to next year when the birthday has passed already this year? The OP's comments make no mention of needing to do that; in fact, he explicitly mentions date in January of this year.

Comment: @salathe what is purpose of this additional parameter in date function like date(m.mkt())  as i know m for month? then why mkt()

Comment: it is to make sure it is in timestamp format.  It is MakeTime

Comment: @SariRahal so you mean date can take two parameter? can you give a example where you didn't use mkt()?

Answer (score 0):

```
$age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $year, $month, $day))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$year)-1):(date("Y")-$year));
```

Comment: Whether this is correct or not is up to the OP. However, a short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.